# Prevent test classes to be visible in source in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit

Assume a typical maven project in eclipse `src/{main,test}/{java,resources}`.
Now being in a class in `src/main/java` I can see and compile against classes from `src/test/java` – what of course is wrong and not desired.

A second problem is, that having the same class in a `src/test/java` as in `src/main/java` results in a resource duplication error, although this compiles fine (and on purpose) with `mvn test`.

How can I tweak my eclipse so it compiles correctly test classes and hides test classes in normal source code?

Comment: why don't make a separate project for your tests ? also you can suffix your test class name with `Test` so that there is no confusion

Comment: Do you really have the same class in `src/test/java` as in `src/main/java´. I have usually a implementation in `src/main/java` and the appropriate test in `src/test/java` which is named like `WhatEverTest.java´ ...in `src/main/java` i have never classes named `WhatEverTest.java`.....Furthermore i would be astonished if you could access class from `src/test/java` in `src/main/java` Can you make an example project of such case? Furthermore if you are in Eclipse this is a different world..

Comment: @flafoux separate projects would double the project count in maven setups.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, the current project uses this concept to mock static singletons for tests - it is a dicussable architecture. But works in NetBeans and maven.
Any project in eclipse works that way :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a very old eclipse problem. not sure if it's possible to bypass it. easiest thing would be to use CI server that runs maven from the command line

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it is actually a known bug from 2008 :(
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224708